# Tensorflow Check failed: work_element_count > 0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

Does anybody know how to deal with Tensorflow 'work_element_count' errors?

> F ./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h:127] Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs. 0)
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Here is part of my source code:

```
class DiscriminatorModel:
    def __init__(self, session, some_parameters):
        self.sess = session
        self.parameters = some_parameters

    def build_feed_dict(self, input_frames, gt_output_frames, generator):
        feed_dict = {}
        batch_size = np.shape(gt_output_frames)[0]
        print(batch_size) # 1

        print(np.shape(generator.input_frames_train))   # (?,7,32,32,32,1)
        print(np.shape(input_frames))                   # (1,7,32,32,32,1)
        print(np.shape(generator.gt_frames_train))      # (?,7,32,32,32,1)
        print(np.shape(gt_output_frames))               # (1,7,32,32,32,1)

        g_feed_dict={generator.input_frames_train:input_frames,
                     generator.gt_frames_train:gt_output_frames}

        def getshape(d):
            if isinstance(d, dict):
                return {k:getshape(d[k]) for k in d}
            else:
                return None
        print("g_feed_dict shape :", getshape(g_feed_dict),"\n")
        # {<tf.Tensor 'generator/data/Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 32, 1) dtype=float32>: None, <tf.Tensor 'generator/data/Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 32, 1) dtype=float32>: None}

        print(sys.getsizeof(generator.scale_preds_train))    # 96
        print(sys.getsizeof(g_feed_dict))                    # 288


        # error occurs here.
        g_scale_preds = self.sess.run(generator.scale_preds_train, feed_dict=g_feed_dict)
        # F ./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_launch_config.h:127] Check failed: work_element_count > 0 (0 vs. 0)
        # Aborted (core dumped)

    def train_step(self, batch, generator):
        print(np.shape(batch))    # [1, 7, 32, 32, 32, 2]
        input_frames = batch[:, :, :, :, :, :-1]
        gt_output_frames = batch[:, :, :, :, :, -1:]

        feed_dict = self.build_feed_dict(input_frames, gt_output_frames, generator)

class GeneratorModel:
    def __init__(self, session, some_parameters):
        self.sess = session
        self.parameters = some_parameters

        self.input_frames_train = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32, shape=[None, 7, 32, 32, 32, 1])
        self.gt_frames_train = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32, shape=[None, 7, 32, 32, 32, 1])

        self.input_frames_test = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32, shape=[None, 7, 32, 32, 32, 1])
        self.gt_frames_test = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32, shape=[None, 7, 32, 32, 32, 1])

        self.scale_preds_train = []
        for p in range(4):
            # scale size, 4 --> 8 --> 16 --> 32
            sc = 4*(2**p)
            # this passes tf.Tensor array of shape (1,7,sc,sc,sc,1)
            train_preds = calculate(self.width_train,
                                    self.height_train,
                                    self.depth_train,
                                    ...)
            self.scale_preds_train.append(train_preds

        # [ <..Tensor shape=(1,7,4,4,4,1) ....>,
        #   <..Tensor shape=(1,7,8,8,8,1) ....>,
        #   <..Tensor shape=(1,7,16,16,16,1)..>,
        #   <..Tensor shape=(1,7,32,32,32,1)..> ]
        print(self.scale_preds_train)

sess = tf.Session()
d_model = DiscriminatorModel(sess, some_parameters)
g_model = GeneratorModel(sess, some_parameters)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# this returns numpy array of shape [1,7,32,32,32,2]
batch = get_batch()

# trouble here.
d_model.train_step(batch, g_model)
```

I've seen some recommendations about:

- use CUDA 9.0 / cuDNN 7.0 / tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0 (--> I'm already using these)
- check if batch has size greater than 0 (--> it seems they are.)
- do not use more gpus than the number of samples in a batch (--> I do not)

I use single 11GB gpu among 5 of them, specified as

```
~$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python3 foo.py
```

and the batch size is 1.
Can anyone tell the missing points or things I've done wrong?

## Edit 1.

I found a case that gets through this error. If I give some modification to input like

```
# ... previous code does not change
print(sys.getsizeof(g_feed_dict))                    # 288
temp_index = 0
temp_input = [generator.scale_preds_train[temp_index],
              generator.scale_preds_train[temp_index],
              generator.scale_preds_train[temp_index],
              generator.scale_preds_train[temp_index]]
# this <temp_input> does not raise error here.
# however temp_index > 0 don't work.
g_scale_preds = self.sess.run(temp_input, feed_dict=g_feed_dict)
```

This makes input passed to the `sess.run` with its shape something like

`[(1,7,4,4,4,1), (1,7,4,4,4,1), (1,7,4,4,4,1), (1,7,4,4,4,1)]`

which should be (originally) list of scaled shapes like [(1,7,4,4,4,1), (1,7,8,8,8,1), (1,7,16,16,16,1), (1,7,32,32,32,1)].
Also, the arrays in the dictionary `feed_dict` is of shape
`(1,7,32,32,32,1)`.

It seems like the error comes from tensorflow-gpu trying to reach wrong indices of array (where the memory is not allocated actually) therefore the "work element is count 0" (But I'm not sure yet).

I cannot understand why the `temp_index > 0` (e.g. `1`, `2`, `3`) does throw same 
`Check failed` error, while `0` is the only shape that does not.

## Edit 2.

After I changed my gpu from TITAN Xp to GeForce GTX, the error log said

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

at the same code (sess.run).

Comment: This error has nothing to do with CUDA, it is something internal to Tensorflow, and I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: @talonmies Thanks! Now I find it irrelevant w/ cuda. Still suffering from that Tensorflow yet. And I've edited some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've solved it..

Just as the GTX error log had told me, there was something becomes zero, and was actually a denominator (thus irrelevant with all of those code above). Specifications at the last debug is as follows:

CUDA 8.0 / Tensorflow 1.8.0

with GeForce GTX of course. I think the log showed different (and slightly more detailed) because of versions rather than the actual GPU, even though different version itself did not solve indeed.

Comment: and surely worked well with previous versions (cuda 9.0 / tf 1.8 ). I think those versions don't matter in this case, except for showing different logs.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, one of the conv layers has 0 output feature maps, which causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was training the model on Colab and got the same problem. The issue was 'num_classes', in the config file it was set to 2 while my model had 36 classes.

You should consider paying attention to num_classes in your config file.